# Can't upload video on Youtube with apis v3

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to upload automatically videos to my YouTube account. The code below should log me in and then upload the video.

The app apparently works and says that the video is uploaded but no video was really uploaded

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
    Console.WriteLine("==============================");

    try
    {
        new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private async Task Run()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/credentials")
        );
    }

    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        //ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
    });

    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
    video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\Adriano\source\repos\UploadYoutube\output.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
    }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case UploadStatus.Uploading:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
            break;

        case UploadStatus.Failed:
            Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
            break;
    }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
}
```

And this is appearing on the console.

## YouTube Data API: Upload Video

10485760 bytes sent.
20971520 bytes sent.
31457280 bytes sent.
41943040 bytes sent.
Video id 'XXQGD6ZfYKs' was successfully uploaded.
Press any key to continue...

Comment: Ok so what makes you think that the video is not uploaded? Did you check your account under private videos?  Remember YouTube is channel based when you logged in you picked a channel check that channel.  Also remember that videos will be uploaded as private until you application has gone though the review process.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to edit the code but already try to change from private to public but on the channel says that youtube made it private for some reasons

Comment: You dont understand by default any video uploaded via the YOuTube API will be private until your application has gone though the verification process with Google.  So does your video appear on your channel under private videos?

Comment: oh okay sorry i didn't know that. how can i make this verification?

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

there are sevral things that could cause you to not be able to find your video even though it apears to be uploaded.

First off remember that the Youtube API is channel based when you authorized your application you picked a channel.  Make sure that you are checking this channel in Youtube if you cant remember which channel you picked the easiest thing to do would be to reauthorize your application to do that change "user" to something else this will cause the code to request authrization again or go into "{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/credentials" and look for the credentials file that was created by your application delete it and it will request authorization again.

The second problem could be that you are not checking for private videos.  YouTube videos uploaded via the api will appear as private if the application has not been though the [verification process](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).

Comment: hi there, i can see you have much experience in Google APIs , i have some query and required suggestion, as i am also working on google apis since long time. can we be in a chat group ? @DalmTo